# Turning one-hot encoded table into 2D table of counts

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I think I can solve this problem without too much difficulty but suspect that any solution I come up with will be sub-optimal, so am interested in how the real pandas experts would do it; I'm sure I could learn something from that.

I have a table of data that is one-hot encoded, something like:

```
Index.  A1.     A2.     A3.     B1.     B2.     C1.     C2.     C3.     C4.     
0.      True.   False.  True.   True.   True.   False.  True.   False.  False.  
...
```

So every entry is a Boolean and my columns consist of several groups of categories (the A's, B's and C's).

What I want to create is new DataFrames where I pick any two categories and get a table of counts of how many people are in the pair of categories corresponding to that row/column. So, if I was looking at categories A and B, I would generate a table:

```
Index.  A1.     A2.     A3.   None    Total 
B1.     x11.    x12.    x13.  x1N     x1T
B2.     x21.    x22.    x23.  x2N.    x2T
None.   xN1.    xN2.    xN3.  xNN     xNT
Total.  xT1.    xT2.    xT3.  xTN     xTT
```

where x11 is the count of rows in the original table that have both A1 and B1 True, x12 is the count of those rows that have A1 and B2 True, and so on.

I'm also interested in the counts of those entries where all the A values were False and/or all the B values were false, which are accounted for in the None columns.

Finally, I would also like the totals of rows where any of the columns in the corresponding category were True. So x1T would be the number of rows where B1 was True and any of A1, A2 or A3 were True, and so on (note that this is not just the sum of x11, x12 and x13 as the categories are not always mutually exclusive; a row could have both A1 True and A2 True for example). xNN is the number of rows that have all false values for A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, and xTT is the number of rows that have at least one true value for any of A1, A2, A3, B1 and B2, so xNN + xTT would equal the total number of rows in the original table.

Thanks
Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach:

```
def get_table(data, prefix):
    '''
    get the columns in the respective category
    and assign `none` and `Total` columns
    '''
    return (df.filter(like=prefix)
              .assign(none=lambda x: (1-x).prod(1),
                      Total=lambda x: x.any(1))
           )

# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True,False], size=(5,9), p=(0.6,0.4)),
                 columns=[f'{x}{y}'for x in 'ABC' for y in '123'])

# the output
df = df.astype(int)
get_table(df, 'B').T @ get_table(df, 'A')
```

Output:

```
      A1 A2 A3 none Total
B1     3  2  1    0     3
B2     3  2  1    0     3
B3     2  1  1    0     2
none   0  0  1    0     1
Total  4  3  2    0     5
```

Here I don't understand as why `(none, Total)` must be zero. Since `none` corresponds to all `False` in `B` and `Total` corresponds to some `True` in `A`.

Comment: You are correct about the zeroes; that was my mistake and I corrected it. Fantastic answer, thank you! I knew someone would have a much better solution than I could come up.